# Closing a File in Python

Tags: python, file, spyder, python-3.8

I'm writing a code in Python on Spyder, using Tkinter. You can see one of my methods below. Didn't want to put my full code because it's pretty long. I need to open a file to read some information. There is not a problem in my code and it actually works pretty well (does what i want it to do) but I couldn't figure out how to close my file after I'm done with it. Wherever i put my 'myFile.close()' command it gives me another type of error. I want to learn about where should i put it. I'm a little confused about where to put it because of for and if's. Would you please help me?

*** EDITED ***
With the myFile1.close() commands below it gives an "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." error.

- I didn't use myFile1 in another place.
- There isn't another myFile1.close() command.

```
    def login(self):
        id_val = self.entry_1.get()
        pass_val = self.entry_2.get()
        myFile1 = open("ids.txt", "r")
        for line in myFile1:
            if line.find(id_val) == 0:
                self.pid,password,name,gender,age,phone=line.split(",")
                if password == pass_val:
                    box = Text(width=45, height=40)
                    box.place(x=1120, y=80)
                    self.first,self.last=name.split()
                    box.insert(END, "\n\n\tAd: ")
                    box.insert(INSERT, self.first)
                    box.insert(END, "\n\n\tSoyad: ")
                    box.insert(INSERT, self.last)        
                    box.insert(END, "\n\n\tCinsiyet: ")
                    box.insert(INSERT, gender)
                    box.insert(END, "\n\n\tYaş: ")
                    box.insert(INSERT, age)
                    box.insert(END, "\n\n\tTelefon: ")
                    box.insert(INSERT, phone)
                    self.patient_screen()
                    myFile1.close()
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Warning", "Wrong ID or password.")
                    myFile1.close()
                    break
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Warning", "Wrong ID or password.")
                myFile1.close()
                break
```

Comment: Where exactly you are closing your file?

Comment: Can you please post your trace log? I'm actually interested, what could be wrong with myFile1.close().

Comment: Where did you put it, and what is the error? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: There isn't a command to close it on here because wherever i put it i got an error. I deleted before I asked. There are 3 possible ways to quit this function but even though i tried to put it on every way it gave me another error. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: It's myFile1.close()

Comment: For example: 
If I put the command at the end of every possible way 
(before self.patient_screen / before break / before break)
It gives 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.' error

Comment: Edit your question with the actual code that produces the error so we can reproduce it and see what you’re doing wrong. Include the full trace back of the error.

Comment: Closing it after patient screen closes it in the middle of looping. The ones before the breaks should be fine. But using a `with` as the answers show is the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct, but poor way to open and close a file:

```
f = open(filename,...)
# do something with f
f.close()
```

It works, but there are problems. What if you want to `return` in the middle of it, or `break`, or there is an exception? Then you'd have to do this:

```
f = open(filename, ...)
# do something with f
if condition:
    f.close()
    return something
# do something else with f
try:
    # do something which may fail
except:
    f.close()
    raise
if another condition:
    f.close()
    return something_else
# do more  with f
f.close()
```

This gets ugly quickly. In order to avoid that, it is best to use the context manager protocol to open files using `with` keyword, as those close automatically.

The same complex example:

```
with open(filename, ...) as f:
    # do something with f
    if condition:
        return something
    # do something else with f
    # do something which may fail
    if another condition:
        return something_else
    # do more  with f

# here, the file is closed automatically
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for the explanation about why it fixes the error! With some changes it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Spyder or Tkinter but I would suggest using [context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) with files, it ensures that the resource is closed after the context manager.

```
def login(self):
        id_val = self.entry_1.get()
        pass_val = self.entry_2.get()
        # myFile1 = open("ids.txt", "r")
        with open("ids.txt", "r") as myFile1 :
            for line in myFile1:
                if line.find(id_val) == 0:
                    self.pid,password,name,gender,age,phone=line.split(",")
                    if password == pass_val:
                        box = Text(width=45, height=40)
                        box.place(x=1120, y=80)
                        self.first,self.last=name.split()
                        box.insert(END, "\n\n\tAd: ")
                        box.insert(INSERT, self.first)
                        box.insert(END, "\n\n\tSoyad: ")
                        box.insert(INSERT, self.last)        
                        box.insert(END, "\n\n\tCinsiyet: ")
                        box.insert(INSERT, gender)
                        box.insert(END, "\n\n\tYaş: ")
                        box.insert(INSERT, age)
                        box.insert(END, "\n\n\tTelefon: ")
                        box.insert(INSERT, phone)
                        self.patient_screen()
                    else:
                        messagebox.showerror("Warning", "Wrong ID or password.")
                        break
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Warning", "Wrong ID or password.")
                    break
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but because of it's explanation i need to give it to the other answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Caleb's answer: for readability, I highly recommend flattening the code by checking for errors first so that you can break out of the loop quickly, then continuing on at the same level of indentation because you know you're no longer in an error state. For instance:

```
def login(self):
    id_val = self.entry_1.get()
    pass_val = self.entry_2.get()
    with open("ids.txt", "r") as myFile1 :
        for line in myFile1:
            if line.find(id_val) != 0:
                messagebox.showerror("Warning", "Wrong ID or password.")
                break

            # If you've reached this line, you know the ID is correct.
            self.pid,password,name,gender,age,phone=line.split(",")
            if password != pass_val:
                messagebox.showerror("Warning", "Wrong ID or password.")
                break

            # If you've reached this line, you know the password is correct.
            box = Text(width=45, height=40)
            box.place(x=1120, y=80)
            self.first,self.last=name.split()
            box.insert(END, "\n\n\tAd: ")
            box.insert(INSERT, self.first)
            box.insert(END, "\n\n\tSoyad: ")
            box.insert(INSERT, self.last)        
            box.insert(END, "\n\n\tCinsiyet: ")
            box.insert(INSERT, gender)
            box.insert(END, "\n\n\tYaş: ")
            box.insert(INSERT, age)
            box.insert(END, "\n\n\tTelefon: ")
            box.insert(INSERT, phone)
            self.patient_screen()
```

It's a lot more readable when you don't have a whole bunch of nested `if` statements.

Comment: Wow, it looks so much better, thank you so much! For the rest of the code I will try to check for errors first!